# How to autoconnect an ad-hoc network?

Tags: network-manager, adhoc

If I use the network connection editor to create a new wifi ad-hoc network, I can see it on another computer and connect to it.

However, the other computer connects automatically if and only the network is established by the first one.

As per definition, ad-hoc networks have no master and any participant has the same role.

So why does the ad-hoc network behave differently at the two machines, and how can I achieve both machines connect the ad-hoc network automatically, independent of the presence of another one?

Comment: Probably because each each computer has a different MAC address. Even if the SSIDs are the same, the MAC will be different.

Comment: Yes, the MACs differ (as they should). But Ad-Hoc networks only use the MAC (or even something other) for their initial so-called 'cell id', and should select an equal cell id based on the SSID. 

It seems NetworkManager likes to assign the traditional roles like 'Access Point' and 'Station' even on Ad-Hoc networks, where there shouldn't be such distinction.